# Group and subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I just learned that a group is a set together with an operation such as $<G,•>$.

And a subgroup is a subset H of G, which forms a group under "•".

I got confused by the definitions because I think subgroup should be a group and it should be $<H,•>$. Is that right?

Comment: People often write $H$ to mean $\langle H,\bullet\rangle$ when the operation $\bullet$ is obvious from context.

Comment: "H forms a group under $\cdot$" is the same statement as "<H, $\cdot$> is a group."  <$\mathbb N$+{0}, + > is a group.  Even Numbers $\subset \mathbb N$+{0}.  Even Numbers is a group under addition $\iff$ <Even Numbers, +> is a group.  Note though that Odd Numbers is *not* a group under addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely correct.

(But, be aware that groups and subgroups are often referred to just as, for example, $G$, without specifying an operation, when the writer assumes that you will know what operation is being talked about.)

(Specifically, if we talk about "a subgroup $H$ of $<G, \cdot>$", the operation could only be $\cdot$, so we don't need to say "a subgroup $<H, \cdot>$ ..." even though that's really what we mean.)

Comment: Thanks, and another question is that is Group a set or it just a group(not a set).

Answer (score 1):

Correct, a group is a set with 3 properties

1. Has an identity element
2. Is closed under the operation • (whatever • may be)

   3. Is closed under inverses

An important point to note is that H is not just any group but one that borrows the identity element and operation from G. It's properties:

1. Has the same identity element as G
2. Is closed under the same operation as the one in G
3. Is closed under inverses

Comment: Groups also have to satisfy the associativity property.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying "a subgroup $H$ should be a group...". I will pause here, and ask *under what operation*? We expect that it should be group under same operation as in $G$.

The same is said in first two lines: $H$ is a subset, such that it becomes group under same $\bullet$ as in $G$.